# Object.values on a realmjs object returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm-js

## Description

I'm trying to convert my realm object to an array as can be seen below in the history method.

```
class RealmStore {

    @observable symptoms = {};
    @observable meals    = {};

    @computed get history(){
        return [...Object.values(this.symptoms), ...Object.values(this.meals)];
    }

    //More methods to populate this.symptoms and this.meals
}
```

When I log `this.symptoms` I get the following output in my terminal:

```
{
  '0': {
    date: Fri Jun 29 2018 15: 56: 48 GMT + 0200(CEST),
    name: 'Regurgitation',
    value: 1
  },
  '1': {
    date: Fri Jun 29 2018 15: 58: 09 GMT + 0200(CEST),
    name: 'Belching',
    value: 1
  },
  '2': {
    date: Fri Jun 29 2018 16: 10: 39 GMT + 0200(CEST),
    name: 'Heartburn',
    value: 2
  },
  '3': {
    date: Fri Jun 29 2018 23: 30: 36 GMT + 0200(CEST),
    name: 'Heartburn',
    value: 1
  }
}
```

When I log `Object.keys(this.symptoms)` I get the following in my terminal:

```
[ '0', '1', '2', '3' ]
```

When I log `Object.values(this.symptoms)` I get the following in my terminal:

```
[]
```

**This is the only way that this works:**

```
        const values = [];
        for(let prop in this.symptoms){
            if(this.symptoms.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                values.push(this.symptoms[prop])
            }
        }
        console.log(values);
```

This logs the following in my terminal:

```
[{
    date: Fri Jun 29 2018 15: 56: 48 GMT + 0200(CEST),
    name: 'Regurgitation',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    date: Fri Jun 29 2018 15: 58: 09 GMT + 0200(CEST),
    name: 'Belching',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    date: Fri Jun 29 2018 16: 10: 39 GMT + 0200(CEST),
    name: 'Heartburn',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    date: Fri Jun 29 2018 23: 30: 36 GMT + 0200(CEST),
    name: 'Heartburn',
    value: 1
  }
]
```

## Question:

What is causing the realmjs object to be unable to return an array of values?

Comment: Can you share the `observable` function please

Comment: Can this be because of the `date` property?

Comment: @bambam I'm sorry, I don't understand your request to share the observable function as there is none?

Comment: @bennygenel I was thinking the same thing, but it shouldn't be an issue since date is just a date object? It works with a for iterable loop.

Comment: The observable decorator is a function that gets applied to the property. I just want to see if that does anything to the values. Is Object.values(this.meals) also empty?

Comment: @bambam https://gist.github.com/rottenoats/7908b5c8d36ad47bb28c42f8e542a29a and yes it's empty as I haven't populated the meals in realm yet, so it's expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently unsure as to why `Object.values()` does not work. I went ahead and used this alternative, which according to some posts may cause performance issues.

```
Array.from(this.symptoms);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this was due to inconsistent data types in the data available in Atlas. e.g. The date field in schema was of type 'Date' but some values in the collection were carrying the 'string' type. Having consistent data types solved the issue for me.